# In the jq utility, should contains([""]) return true when the array being tested does not contain ""?

Tags: arrays, string, jq, contains

I expect the last test to be false in the following.

```
$ echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq 'contains(["a"])'
true
$ echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq 'contains(["d"])'
false
$ echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq 'contains([""])'
true
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
$
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Add language-specific tag. Is it PHP?

Comment: @PM77-1 `jq` is a command-line JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

From the jq [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

> A string B is contained in a string A if B is a substring of A. An array B is contained in an array A if all elements in B are contained in any element in A.

`""` is a substring of `"a"` (and `"b"` and `"c"`), so `"a"` contains `""` and therefore `["a","b","c"]` contains `[""]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected. From the documentation for `contains` (emphasis mine):

> An array B is contained in an array A if all elements in B
>          are contained in any **element in A**.

So it's not checking if `""` is an element of `A`, but rather if `""` is contained in one of the elements of `A`, and the empty string is a substring of every string.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what I intend, which is to determine if the array contains the empty string as an element.

```
$ echo '["a","","b"]' | jq 'any(.=="")'
true
$ echo '["a","b"]' | jq 'any(.=="")'
false
$
```

Thanks to those who responded.